# How to run http request until 400 is returned

Tags: jmeter

1. Ran JDBC request and got result
   JDBC request : select id from epx.unavailability where startdate >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days') and siteid='${su-siteid}';

Result: Please refer screen shot
[image]

Created HTTP request to delete records which is retrieved from the DB request.

It deleted first record but I want to delete all the records which is reteieved from the DB request.

I'm using ' JSR223 PreProcessor ' to HTTP request.

JSR223 PreProcessor:
def Scenario = vars.get("Scenario")
def unavailabilityid = vars.get("${unavailabilityid}")

if(Scenario.contains("epx_diary_Unavailability_Del_old")){
vars.put("unavailabilityid","${__groovy(vars.getObject('unavailabilityid')[0].get('id'),)}")
}

Please let me know it's possible

Answer (score 0):

If you set "Variable names" in [JDBC Request](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter-1707509382874) sampler:

[image]

you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
id_1=foo
id_2=bar
id_3=baz
...
etc
id_#=number of rows returned by SQL query
```

The `${id}` variable can be used in [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

[image]

ForEach Controller will run its children as many times as there are "ids" returned by your SQL query and you will be able to refer the current "id" as `${id}` in the HTTP Request sampler:

[image]